# C# condition that works outside of method

Tags: c#

```
double positions = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
 
if (textBox3.Text == "Long")
{
    positions = positions;
}

if (textBox3.Text == "Short")
{
    positions = positions * -1;
}
```

Is there any other way I can use a condition where if the textbox3 says "Long" it will convert position to + and if it says "Short" converts the position number to negative. I don't want to use if statement because it creates two different blocks of code. I just want one block.

For example:
if textbox3 is Long or short:
convert position to negative or positive, then
I'm able to use position in a method below.

Comment: what about "long" or "shrt"?  A checkbox or possibly combobox selection would seem more appropriate

Comment: *"I just want one block"* - Since the first block doesn't really do anything, why not just get rid of it?  Then you'd just have one `if` block.

Comment: `positions = (9 - textBox3.Length * 2) * double.Parse(textBox2.Text);` - let's have some fun

Answer (score 0):

you can declare positions with inline if statement :

```
double positions =  textBox3.Text == "short" ? 
Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) * (-1) : 
Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
```

if you want do something else when textBox3.Text == "Long" :

```
double positions =  textBox3.Text == "short" ? 
Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) * (-1) : 
textBox3.Text == "Long" ?
// do something on Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) :
Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need 1 statement, another statement doestn't do anything

```
if (textBox3.Text == "Short") positions = -positions;
```

or you can put everytning in one line

```
double positions =  textBox3.Text == "Short" ?
 - Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text) : Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can negate the `position`. This way you only need 1 operation.

`if (textBox3.Text == "Long" || textBox3.Text == "Short") { positions = positions * -1; }`

Ideally you want to do this in a method and pass a string parameter.

Comment: That will not produce the desired result, check the question again.